# Pause/resume video recording using AVCaptureMovieFileOutput

Tags: ios, iphone, avfoundation, avcapturemoviefileoutput

I am recording file using `AVCaptureMovieFileOutput` by using this method:

```
startRecordingToOutputFileURL: recordingDelegate:
```

Now i want to incorporate pause/resume functionality while recording video.

Please guide me how is this achievable ?

Comment: [This question has already been asked before and there's an answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18073586/pause-resume-video-capture-using-avcapturemoviefileoutput-and-avcapturevideoda) (although it's not accepted).  Does it work for you?

Comment: Check this out: https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/AVFoundation/Reference/AVCaptureFileOutput_Class/#//apple_ref/occ/instm/AVCaptureFileOutput/pauseRecording

Comment: @MichaelDautermann I have given it a try. But when I set enabled of my AVCaptureConnection to NO, 
- (void)captureOutput:(AVCaptureFileOutput *)captureOutput didFinishRecordingToOutputFileAtURL:(NSURL *)outputFileURL fromConnections:(NSArray *)connections error:(NSError *)error
is called which is not what I want.

Comment: @cyberlobe I have seen that but unfortunately pauseRecording is available only for MacOS, whereas I want it for iOS

Comment: and does setting "`enabled`" back to `YES` continue the recording?

Comment: No it doesn't continue recording.

Comment: can someone help me? 

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31778386/what-do-i-make-the-delegate-for-avcapturemoviefileoutput-trying-to-record-video

Comment: @MalikBoy Did you get the solution?

Comment: Did you or @AnuragSharma find a solution?

Comment: @Crashalot yes, I got the solution at that time. You need an encoder. Give me your email id I will send it to you or any other way possible.

Comment: Anurag, I know this post is a couples years old, but I need to do this same thing... how did you end up solving it?